# gnuplot: interactive 3D animations?

Tags: animation, 3d, gnuplot, interactive

With gnuplot you can create a 3D-like plot with `splot` and interactively change the view.
[image]

You also can create animations with gnuplot with `set terminal gif animate`.

[image]

```
### interactive animation?
reset session
set view equal
set border 0
unset tics

$Data <<EOD
1   1.000   0.000   0.000
2   0.500   0.866   0.000
3   -0.500  0.866   0.000
4   -1.000  0.000   0.000
5   -0.500  -0.866  0.000
6   0.500   -0.866  0.000
1   1.000   0.000   0.000
EOD

$Off <<EOD
1   0.00    0.00    0.1
2   0.00    0.00    -0.1
3   0.00    0.00    0.1
4   0.00    0.00    -0.1
5   0.00    0.00    0.1
6   0.00    0.00    -0.1
1   0.00    0.00    0.1
EOD

set xrange[-2:2]
set yrange[-2:2]
set zrange[-2:2]
set view 45,45
max=10.
Offset(n,axis,i) = real(word($Off[n+1],axis+1))*sin(2*pi*i/max)

set term gif animate delay 5 size 400,300
set output "Molecule.gif"

do for [i=0:max] {
    splot $Data u ($2+Offset($0,1,i)):($3+Offset($0,2,i)):($4+Offset($0,3,i)) \
    w lp pt 7 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "red" not
    unset autoscale
}

set term wxt size 400,300
set margin 0
splot $Data u 2:3:4 w lp pt 7 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "red" not
set output
### end of code
```

Now, my question is: is there maybe the chance to also create interactive animations? I would like to rotate the view while it is animated. Is this somehow possible with gnuplot? Any ideas?

**Edit:**

@Ethan's answer solves this question. However, is there maybe a way to avoid the flickering of the mouse cursor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the plot commands in a loop does not disable mouse interaction.  The simple answer should work:

```
set xrange[-2:2]
set yrange[-2:2]
set zrange[-2:2]
set view 45,45
Offset(n,axis,i) = real(word($Off[n+1],axis+1))*sin(2*pi*i/max)

# Loop forever
# but allow an explicit end condition triggered by a hot key
done = 0
bind "d" "done = 1"

while (!done) {
  do for [i=0:10] {
    splot $Data u ($2+Offset($0,1,i)):($3+Offset($0,2,i)):($4+Offset($0,3,i)) \
    w lp pt 7 ps 2 lw 2 lc rgb "red" not
    pause 0.1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ok, sure, of course an endless loop ;-). I didn't know how to escape from it. Learned again. Is there maybe a way to avoid the flickering of the mouse cursor? (see edited question)

Comment: I see no flickering with any of the interactive terminals available to me (qt wxt x11).  I would guess what you see has something to do with the video driver configuration used by your desktop.

Comment: I'm working with Win7 and Win10. I do see this flickering behaviour on a wxt terminal. However, I don't see it on a qt terminal (well, I see some flickering also on the gnuplot console but not in the qt window). I don't have a x11 terminal. Solution: switch to qt terminal. Thanks!